# How to test the difference between two groups in their number of correct, incorrect, and missed trials?

Tags: repeated-measures, multinomial-distribution

Imagine I have 2 groups (3 healthy controls and 4 schizophrenia patients). During a limited time, they either answered to questions correctly, incorrectly, or didn't answer (missed trials). How can I test whether there is a difference between these two groups regarding the number of correct, incorrect, and missed trials.

I’d appreciate if you explain it elaborately.

[image]

Comment: The question of how to analyze these data is an on topic statistical question. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: Be aware that questions about how to use software are generally off topic here. You may not get an answer to the "how to do it in SPSS" part.

Comment: alright, I changed it to an SPSS-free question